# Splitting a Phone Number into a List of Digits: Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I currently am trying to split up a string that is supposed to be a phone number into a list of just the individual digits. I'm doing this as a way to error proof the field where the user enters the information.

For example:

If the user enters: 
123 456-7890

I want to output the list : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

I currently am running:

```
numbersList = [int(s) for s in str.split(unformattedPhone) if s.isdigit()]
```

However this keeps getting hung up by treating 920 as a separate number and doesn't split on the hyphen either. I think theres a way to do this with regex but I'm not very good with that. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you don't have to use the `split` function if you just want to get all the characters separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over string.

**Ex:**

```
unformattedPhone = "123 456-7890"
numbersList = [int(s) for s in unformattedPhone if s.isdigit()]
print(numbersList)
```

**Output"**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: This works, but using `list()` is unnecessary here: `for s in unformattedPhone if...` will work just fine.

Comment: @BenJones. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = '123 456-7890'
new_s = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d', s)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also remove all the non digits `\D`:

```
import re
unformattedPhone = "123 456-7890"
nrs = [int(i) for i in re.sub('\D', '', unformattedPhone)]
print(nrs)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```